# Confusion creating brew formula - cmake cache specifications, depends_on layout options

Tags: macos, boost, cmake, homebrew

I am attempting to create a brew formula to streamline installing DAKOTA on osx. In order to install DAKOTA, I need to run a cmake file configuration file. Here is my attempt at creating a propper brew formula, although I am not sure how to implement the cmake step. I am also not sure how to set the homebrew flags during the "depends on" steps. Am I implementing the install options correctly? How can I change the formula layouts to "system"?

Here is my attempt as of now, although I am unsure about specifying `layout=system` in the `depends_on` implementations, and I cannot find documentation as to how to use `cmake` in a brew formula.

```
class DAKOTA < Formula
  desc "Sandia Lab's DAKOTA"
  homepage "https://dakota.sandia.gov"
  url "https://dakota.sandia.gov/sites/default/files/distributions/public/dakota-6.2-public.src.tar.gz"
  sha256 "53953e477a37d2e870e3be4b22f519474c24537b0e6eb1633e3402273a684a98"

  depends_on "gcc" => ["without-multilib"]
  depends_on "gcc-4.9" => ["without-multilib"]
  depends_on "open-mpi" => ["--C++11"] 
  system "export", "HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-4.9"
  system "export", "HOMEBREW_CXX=gcc-4.9"
  depends_on "boost" => ["C++11", "with-mpi", "without-single"] # can't have layout=tagged, need layout=system

  def install
    system "cmake", "-C", "Buildak.cmake" # not sure how to implement this
    system "make", "install"
    system 'echo', 'echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/dakota/Cellar/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/dakota/test:/usr/local/Cellar/dakota/lib;export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/dakota/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/dakota/lib" >> ~/.bash_profile' # following sandia's installation instructions. editing DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is frowned on by brew doctor, not sure what to do about this.... 
  end

  test do
    system "dakota", "-v" 
    system "dakota", "-i", "/usr/local/Cellar/dakota/test/dakota_rosenbrock.in"
  end
end
```